# ReactiveUI.XamForms ViewModel not initialized

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvm, reactiveui

I'm trying to bind View elements to a ViewModel, but for some reasons the ViewModel is not initialized when the form loaded.  The code is based on the Visual Studio 2022 "Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms)" template with the MainPage.xaml/cs replaced by ReactiveUI V-VM classes (NuGet ReactiveUI.XamForms package).  The app displays the View, but the command, binding, etc. do not work.  I setup a few trace lines and find that the ViewModel classes is never instantiated.  Not sure what I miss here.
Below are the classes:

**View class:**

**ItemPage.xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rxui:ReactiveContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:rxui="clr-namespace:ReactiveUI.XamForms;assembly=ReactiveUI.XamForms"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestDroid.ViewModels" 
    x:Class="TestDroid.Views.ItemPage"
    x:TypeArguments="vm:ItemViewModel"
    x:DataType="vm:ItemViewModel" 
>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="LblCounter" />
        <Button x:Name="BtnIncrement" Text="Increment" />
    </StackLayout>

</rxui:ReactiveContentPage>
```

**ItemPage.xaml.cs:**

```
using ReactiveUI;
using ReactiveUI.XamForms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using TestDroid.ViewModels;

namespace TestDroid.Views
{
    public partial class ItemPage: ReactiveContentPage<ItemViewModel>
    {
        public ItemPage()
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("**** In ItemPage constructor");
            InitializeComponent();

            this.WhenActivated(
                    disposables =>
                    {
                        // this.ViewModel is 'null' here.
                        Trace.WriteLine($"**** in WhenActivated: {this.ViewModel}."); 
                        this.OneWayBind(this.ViewModel, x => x.Counter, x => x.LblCounter.Text)
                            .DisposeWith(disposables);

                        this.BindCommand(this.ViewModel, x => x.IncrementCounter, x => x.BtnIncrement)
                            .DisposeWith(disposables);
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel class:**

**ItemViewModel.cs:**

```
using ReactiveUI;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reactive;

namespace TestDroid.ViewModels
{
    public class ItemViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        private int _counter;

        public int Counter
        {
            get => _counter;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _counter, value);
        }

        private readonly ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> incrementCounter;
        public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> IncrementCounter => this.incrementCounter;

        public ItemViewModel()
        {
            // Execution never gets to this line.
            Trace.WriteLine("**** In ItemViewModel contructor.");  
            Counter = 0;

            this.incrementCounter = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => {
                Counter++;
                Trace.WriteLine($"Current Counter: {Counter++}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never used ReactiveUI, but **1)** Are you sure the viewmodel is automatically created for you? What example are you following, to implement this? **2)** Also, the ReactiveUI X-Forms doc says "Use WireUpControls", which I don't see above.

Comment: 1) Both the View and ViewModel are manually created based on ReactiveUI API document here: https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/data-binding/xamarin-forms  . I replace the automatically created MainPage.xaml and .cs from the VS framework with them.  2) This is how V-VM are normally setup in WPF (which I'm familiar with).  Declare a V extending a Reactive class with an interface of the VM as a template type (eg. class MainView: ReactiveWindow<IMainViewModel>)  then bind controls in code behind.  The form shows up correctly, but no binding because VM is never instantiated.

Comment: Ok. See if view's `BindingContext` gets set.

Comment: You are right.  App works with a call to BindingContext in code behind **this.BindingContext = ViewModel = new ItemViewModel();**

Comment: Or in AXML **<rxui:ReactiveContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:ItemViewModel/>
    </rxui:ReactiveContentPage.BindingContext>** .  Somehow in my WPF code **x:TypeArguments="vm:ItemViewModel"** is enough.

Comment: Good. It is surprising that the Xamarin Forms version of ReactiveUI, didn't automatically add that "usual" XF binding mechanism, so that standard XF Binds would work.